# Javascript function to strip user ID from URL

Tags: javascript, strip

i need a javascript function to strip the user ID from a given URL.
for example. i have this URL http://www.example.com/member.php?id=100001877097904
how can i retrieve the ID of the user from that URL?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getParameterByName(url, name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(url);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: This will find URL parameters inside fragments, for example, in `#?foo=bar`.

Comment: Jenny - If this was the solution do you mind accepting it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/member.php?id=100001877097904",
    id  = (url.match(/[?&#]id=(\d+)/) || []).pop();

console.log(id);
```

Comment: This does a poor job if there are other parameters whose names end in "id", for example "/foo?bid=1&grid=1234&id=2".

Comment: @MikeSamuel How about now? I assume we shouldn't keep in mind other possible delimiters (like `;`).